# Laravel Nova: How to make a resource search title from two fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a resource with first_name and last_name fields. How can I make the title be `first_name . ' ' . last_name` ?

I tried overriding title() but, understandably, first_name and last_name are not properties of the resource class.

```
public function title()
{
   return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely wrong. This code does work. I leave the question here in case it helps someone else.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and then accept it to prevent this showing up as an unanswered question.